# Can I eat beans that have had weeevils in it?

Tags: food-safety, beans

I put two cups of beans to soak overnight. The morning after, I realized there were dead weevils floating in the water.

Should I eat the beans after cleaning them or is it better to just throw them away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per Alan Munn, [Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-you-found-weevils-in-your-food-are-they-harmful-to-eat), and [Iowa State](https://hortnews.extension.iastate.edu/rice-weevil-and-granary-weevil), grain weevils are medically harmless and carry no human diseases.

That said, most people find the thought of eating weevil larvae in their beans disgusting, and beans are pretty cheap to replace.  So unless you're on a ship or a camping trip, just throw them out and start over.

If necessary, you can use the [1-hour hydration method](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-quicksoak-dried-beans-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-198610) for your beans to cook them today.

Comment: In short, you can, but why would you if you have alternative options.

Answer (score 1):

In a word **NO**

You have no idea if they carried disease or other contaminants in, toss the lot.

Comment: Is there any evidence that they do carry diseases that humans might be affected by?

Comment: See e.g. this quora answer https://www.quora.com/If-you-found-weevils-in-your-food-are-they-harmful-to-eat from a Public Health Entomologist.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes. I’ve read the same quora answer and now I’m in doubt. I need evidence to support Steve Chambers’ answer on this topic.

Comment: Well you could eat them and get sick. Not being flippant but really is your health potentially worth the few bucks you spent on a few beans to find out? Besides just: ICK! Bugs in the food (unless you INTEND to cook bugs) is just **nasty**

Comment: Weevils are not disease carriers.  They're unappealing, but harmless.  Or everyone on a ship in the 18th century would have died.

Comment: @FuzzyChef So basically I could eat those beans in terms of health, nevertheless, as beans are very cheap, it would be better to just replace the whole batch

Comment: @franpen I certainly would.  Added as an answer so that you can close this question.